# How to compare two columns using excel

Tags: excel

How to compare column A with Column B If they are matched

Column A

```
111.111.1.11
111.111.1.12
111.111.1.13
111.111.2.11
111.111.2.12
111.111.3.11
```

Column B

```
111.111.2.11
111.111.2.12
111.111.1.12
111.111.1.17
111.111.1.21
```

Expected Output :

```
111.111.2.11
111.111.2.12
111.111.1.12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Start Excel.
Press ALT+F11 to start the Visual Basic editor.
On the Insert menu, click Module.
Enter the following code in a module sheet:



 Sub Find_Matches()
        Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
        ' Set CompareRange equal to the range to which you will
        ' compare the selection.
        Set CompareRange = Range("C1:C5")
        ' NOTE: If the compare range is located on another workbook
        ' or worksheet, use the following syntax.
        ' Set CompareRange = Workbooks("Book2"). _
        '   Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C5")
        '
        ' Loop through each cell in the selection and compare it to
        ' each cell in CompareRange.
        For Each x In Selection
            For Each y In CompareRange
                If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 1) = x
            Next y
        Next x
    End Sub


Press ALT+F11 to return to Excel.
Enter the following data (leave column B empty):
A
111.111.1.11
111.111.1.12
111.111.1.13
111.111.2.11
111.111.2.12
111.111.3.11

put B column blank

C
111.111.2.11
111.111.2.12
111.111.1.12
111.111.1.17
111.111.1.21


Select the range A1:A5.
In Excel 2003 and in earlier versions of Excel, point to Macro on the Tools menu, and then click Macros.

In Excel 2007, click the Developer tab, and then click Macro in the Code group.
Click Find_Matches, and then click Run.
```

You will get expected result in b column